# In Reactjs (with redux/thunk), how to get total cost of all Items in a shopping cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, cart

I'm building a shopping cart that contains a list of items. The user can update the quantity of each item, which adjusts the price of the item. 
Also at the bottom of the cart, there should be a **Total** sum of all the prices that the user has to pay.

My question is how can get all the updated prices, sum them up and show a **Total**. And how can I make that **Total** updates itself as the user changes the quantity of each item?

#### React (Item):

```
class Item extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      quantity: 1,
      price: parseFloat(this.props.product.price.replace(/\$|£|/g, '')).toFixed(2)
    };

    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeHandler(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    this.props.updateSubtotal(this.props.product.price, event.target.value);
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      quantity: target.value,
      price: props.subtotal
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { product, index } = this.props;

    return (
      <li>
        <h3>{product.name}</h3>
        <Input
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
          name="product-quantity"
          value={this.state.quatity}
        />
        <span>
          {'$' + this.state.price}
        </span>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  subtotal: state.products.subtotal
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateSubtotal })(Item);
```

#### Redux (Actions):

```
// UPDATE TOTAL PRICE
export const updateTotal = result => dispatch => {

  // Don't what to do here. Or maybe there's a better solution...
  const newTotal = [];
  newTotal.push(result);

  return dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_TOTAL,
    total: newTotal
  });
};

// UPDATE ITEM PRICE BY QUANTITY
export const updateSubtotal = (price, multiplier) => dispatch => {
  const result = computePrice(price, multiplier);

  // Update cart total      
  dispatch(updateTotal(result));

  return dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_SUBTOTAL,
    subtotal: result
  });
};
```

#### Redux (Reducer):

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  total: [],
  subtotal: 1,
  products: [],
  loading: false
};

const productsReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // Update item price
    case Types.UPDATE_SUBTOTAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        subtotal: action.subtotal
      };

    // Update total
    case Types.UPDATE_TOTAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        total: action.total // -> I'm stuck here
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default productsReducer;
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use a different action to update the total price. Whenever you add a new item to your cart you state will change, yes? In that case, all you need is to write a util that looks something like this:

```
// utils.js

export const totalPrice = (state) => {
    const products = state.products;
    const reducer = (currentTotal, product) => currentTotal + product.price;
    return products.reduce(reducer);
};
```

Then, in your container do something like this:

```
// Cart.js

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { totalPrice } from './utils'; // or wherever else

const Cart = ({ total }) => (
    <div>
        {`Your total is ${total}`}
    </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    total: totalPrice(state),
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
)(Cart);
```

The price will then update automatically every time you add something to `products`.

** ***EDIT*** **

As you requested in the comments, this is another way you can do it if you'd like to keep `total` in the reducer. Note that you won't need the `updateTotal` action anymore.

```
// reducers.js

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    total: 0, // note this is not an array.
    subtotal: 0,  // I also set this to 0 instead.
    products: [],
    loading: false
};

const productsReducer = ( state = INITIAL_STATE, action ) => {
    switch(action.type) {
    case Types.UPDATE_SUBTOTAL:
        const newSubtotal = action.subtotal;
        const newTotal = state.total + (newSubtotal - state.subtotal);
        return {
            ...state,
            subtotal: newSubtotal,
            total: newTotal,
        };
    }
    default:
        return state;
};
```

Even though the above works, I would recommend that you dispatch an action to update the `products` rather than the price, and update everything relevant as a result of that action. If you think about it, it makes sense to update the total/subtotal price, quantity, etc, whenever an item is added to `products`.

One more thing: I'm under the impression [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), as you have used in your reducer, does shallow copies. You'll need to be careful with what you store in the `products` array so that you don't mutate the old state by mistake; remember you always want to return a new state object. You can read more about that [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/immutableupdatepatterns).

Comment: this is a great and clever solution to the problem, but I get myself a bit confused when i put state management logic in a "container" type file versus in action/reducer files.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way to do it in the actions or reducer as @felguerez said?

Comment: @Shaoz @felguerez Yes there is! Look at your reducer, give `total` a value of 0 in your `initialState`. Then, whenever the reducer receives an action of type `Types.UPDATE_SUBTOTAL`, update the value of `total` in the `state` using the `totalPrice` function above. The mapStateToProps you pass to `connect` will then look like: `const mapStateToProps = state => ({ total: state.total })`.

Comment: @nebuler, I'm trying to use your solution in the reducer but it doesn't work. How would you use it? (Sorry, for the question, I'm kinda of a beginner in redux)

Comment: @Shaoz I added what I meant in my previous comment to my answer. Let me know how it goes.